# iOS 8 breaks jQuery UI show/hide when scrolling

Tags: jquery, ios

I'm using jQuery UI show/hide to show and hide my website menus on my responsive layout, and have been doing so for months.  I'm seeing that Safari on iOS 8 (and subsequent updates) isn't working exactly correctly.  The show/hide is working fine, but whenever I scroll, the menus are automatically hiding.  Any suggestions?

OK, here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $(window).width();
    if (windowsize < 950) {
        $('#LeftNavigationContent').hide();
        $('#LeftNavigationContent').attr('class', 'LeftNavigationResponsive');
        $('#LeftNavigationControllerImage').html('Section Menu <div class="Rotate90Clockwise">»</div>');
        $('#LeftNavigationControllerImage').attr('title', 'Show Section Menu');
    }
    else {
        $('#LeftNavigationContent').show();
        $('#LeftNavigationContent').attr('class', 'LeftNavigationNormal');
        $('#LeftNavigationControllerImage').html('Section Menu <div class="Rotate90Clockwise">«</div>');
        $('#LeftNavigationControllerImage').attr('title', 'Hide Section Menu');
    }
}

checkWidth();
$(window).resize(checkWidth);

$('.LeftNavigationController').click(function () {
    $('#LeftNavigationContent').toggle('500');
    if ($('#LeftNavigationControllerImage').html() == 'Section Menu <div class="Rotate90Clockwise">«</div>') {
        $('#LeftNavigationControllerImage').html('Section Menu <div class="Rotate90Clockwise">»</div>');
        $('#LeftNavigationControllerImage').attr('title', 'Show Section Menu');
    } else {
        $('#LeftNavigationControllerImage').html('Section Menu <div class="Rotate90Clockwise">«</div>');
        $('#LeftNavigationControllerImage').attr('title', 'Hide Section Menu');
    }
});
```

});

I don't have a scroll function defined, and, as I said, show/hide works fine on all browsers.  The problem is that #LeftNavigationContent is automatically hiding on scroll on iOS 8 Safari.

Comment: Post reproducible isolated code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more details. Your question makes no sense. You say your problem is that it is working fine, just not in the way you'd expect.

Can't suggest anything when there aren't enough details.

Sounds like something is bugged in a scroll function that is activating the hide().

Has anyone else been in your files? Made any changes?

Until you add detail, my suggestion is to change some stuff and check again to see if it's working. Rinse and repeat.

Good luck.